# ¿Por qué "muriendo lento" y no "lentamente"?

Tags: gramática, adverbios

Me refiero a la canción de Timbiriche y Moderrato/Belinda que dice:

> Si tu no estás, dame una razón para no morir lento.

¿Por qué "lento" y no "lentamente"?  ¿Será por "licencia artística" o regla ortográfica?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Lentamente** es una opción perfectamente válida.

**Lento** es un adverbio con lo que lingüísticamente se llama **sufijo cero**.  Es decir, recibe un sufijo adverbial que es en efecto nulo.  La *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua España* (ASALE/RAE) prefiere llamarlos **adverbios adjetivales** o **adverbios cortos**.  De ellos dice:

> tienen la misma forma que los adjetivos correspondientes, pero carecen, al igual que los demás adverbios, de flexión de género y número. […] Estos nuevos adverbios se pueden coordinar on otros similares, ya que con se consideran adjetivos. (§ 30.3a)

En verdad, no es precisamente que pierdan su flexión, ni que carezcan de sufijo, aunque en el castellano moderno pueda parecerlo.  Es que es la forma neutra, que en la lengua moderna coincide completo <sub>(jeje)</sub> con la masculina.<sup>1</sup>  De la *Gramática*:

> El latín […] también se valía de la recategorización de adjetivos de género neutro en acusativo (multum ‘mucho’ o *facile* ‘fácilmente’) o ablativo (*raro* ‘raramente’). El proceso general de adverbialización de adjetivos se mantuvo, con intensidad variable, en todas las lenguas románicas. La pauta era particularmente productiva en el español antiguo (§ 30.3b)

Hay restricciones en los adjetivos que admiten esta forma del adverbio, he aquí un resumen de las cosas más salientes de la *Gramática*:

> Se documentan tanto en el español europeo como en el americano, pero poseen más vitalidad en este último (§ 30.3c).  El proceso […] está limitado a un número reducido de [los adjetivos] (§ 30.3d).  Se diferencia también de los terminados en *-mente* en que no modifican a los adjetivos ni a los participios (§ 30.3d).  Muchos de ellos forman con el verbo un *predicado complejo* que constituye casi una locución verbal (§ 30.3e).

Siguiendo con un resumen (pero ya no citando directo<sub>/amente</sub>), también hay algunos verbos que admiten ciertos adverbios no marcados y otros que no los admiten (§ 30.3f), y muchas veces al alejar el adverbio no marcado del verbo correspondiente, se le obliga el sufijo *-mente*.  Otros son tan extendidos que se consideran efectivamente ya adverbios propios como *rápido* porque no tienen (o tiene pocas) restricciones en uso (§ 30.3h).  Si hay objeto directo, dificulta el uso del adverbio adjetival (§ 30.3i).

Hay, no obstante, algunas pautas que pueden favorecer el uso.  En particular, los adverbios que expresan similitud y diferencia (§ 30.3l) y los que expresan evaluación, especialmente pero no siempre positiva (§ 30.3m) y en exclamaciones o respuestas (§ 30.3o)

---

<sup>1. Compárese estos ejemplos del portugués, castellano, y asturiano, que todos han heredado el uso del neutro como adverbio: *ele trabalha só os sábados*, *él trabaja solo los sábados* y *elli trabaya solo los sábados*.  En el portugués y castellano, es ambiguo si es que trabaja los sábados y no otros días, o si es que es él el que trabaja y no otras personas.  En el asturiano, con el sufijo neutro *-o*, queda claro que es adverbio y no trabaja otros días.  Si fuese que trabajara sin otros, sería *elli trabaya solu los sábados* con el sufijo masuclino *-u*).</sup>